# whats the equivilent of getCheckedItemCount() for API level < 11?

Tags: android, compatibility

I am using this method to check how many items on a list a checked and I get this error that this method is not available for any SDK older than 11.

What is the equivalent this in API level 8

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`getCheckedItemIds().length` seems to do the trick

Comment: the accepted answer didn't work for me (always returns 0), I had to use the Takhion's[http://stackoverflow.com/a/17367442/903469] answer.

Answer (score 12):

The accepted answer didn't work for me (always returns 0), I had to use the following code:

```
public static int getCheckedItemCount(ListView listView)
{
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) return listView.getCheckedItemCount();
    else
    {
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = listView.getCount() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            if (listView.isItemChecked(i)) count++;
        return count;
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be more efficient to iterate over listView.getCheckedItemPositions() instead (it's a `SparseBooleanArray`) and increment `count++` only when `positions.valueAt(idx)` is true.

Comment: @Joe problem was, if I remember correctly, that `isItemChecked` was the only method working reliably in my case!

Comment: That usually means the `SparseBooleanArray` is being misused.  It is not an array of all the checked items, it is a sparse array of items that have been modified, and the value within the sparse array is a boolean indicating whether it is checked or not.  You cannot use `SparseBooleanArray#size()` to determine `count` -- you have to iterate the `SparseBooleanArray` and check the value to be sure it's true.

Comment: @Joe assuming my memory doesn't betray me, that was indeed my first approach! For some reason I remember it not being consistent across different API version. But then again, I didn't have time to test it properly due to time constraints, and I could be mistaken.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using this code which I believe is efficient and works in all cases:

```
public int getCheckedItemCount() {
    ListView listView = getListView();
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        return listView.getCheckedItemCount();
    }

    SparseBooleanArray checkedItems = listView.getCheckedItemPositions();
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0, size = checkedItems.size(); i < size; ++i) {
        if (checkedItems.valueAt(i)) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Please inform me if you find a case where it doesn't work.