# Why can getCheckedItemCount() run correctly when I set android:minSdkVersion="10"?

Tags: android

When I set android:minSdkVersion="8", the following code can't run,and system prompt me to set android:minSdkVersion="11" 
I set android:minSdkVersion="10", but the code can run correctly, why? Thanks!

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
   @Override
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,long arg3) {
          selectedAndTotal.setText(lv.getCheckedItemCount()+"/"+ lv.getCount());                
}});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That method is guaranteed to work when you run on an API Level 11+ device.

Normally, that method call will crash on an API Level 10 or lower device, throwing a `VerifyError`. If you find that it seems to work on API Level 10 or lower, that indicates that `getCheckedItemCount()` existed on `AbsListView` prior to API Level 11, but that it had been excluded from the Android SDK (via the `@hide` attribute in the Android source code). Relying upon such methods is risky, insofar as there is no guarantee that `AbsListView` on all pre-API Level 11 devices will have that method, or that the method will behave as it does on newer devices.

Answer (score 0):

Sir, when the system prompts you to set is to `android:minSdkVersion="11"`, then please set it to 11 instead of `android:minSdkVersion="10`. In the official docs [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#getCheckedItemCount%28%29), it is mentioned that the method was included in API level 11. It might be helpful to you if you can check [whats the equivilent of getCheckedItemCount() for API level < 11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12330660/whats-the-equivilent-of-getcheckeditemcount-for-api-level-11) question. It seems to give a possible solution if you want to use a similar function for API level less than 11. Hope this helps.