# getCheckedItemIds().length don't return correct value

Tags: android

I have read the topic
[whats the equivilent of getCheckedItemCount() for API level < 11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12330660/whats-the-equivilent-of-getcheckeditemcount-for-api-level-11)
`lv.getCheckItemIds().length` can get correct the sum of checked items,
but `lv.getCheckedItemIds().length` can't, Why? Thanks!

```
private void InitListView(int pos) {
    List<String> msgList = getSMS(pos);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, msgList);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter2);
    lv.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            SetSelectedAndTotal();
        }
    });
}

private void SetSelectedAndTotal(){
    selectedAndTotal.setText(lv.getCheckItemIds().length + "/"+lv.getCheckedItemIds().length+ "/"
            + lv.getCount());       
}
```

Comment: Try this link : https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere/issues/135

Answer (score 1):

```
    public long[] getCheckItemIds ();
```

**This method was deprecated in API level 8.**

Use `getCheckedItemIds()` instead which returns the set of checked items ids. The result is only valid if the choice mode has not been set to CHOICE_MODE_NONE.

**Returns**

A new array which contains the id of each checked item in the list.

```
   public long[] getCheckedItemIds ();
```

Returns the set of checked items ids. The result is only valid if the choice mode has not been set to CHOICE_MODE_NONE and the adapter has stable IDs.

```
(hasStableIds() == true)
```

**Returns**

A new array which contains the id of each checked item in the list.

Check out [Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#getCheckItemIds%28%29) for more details.

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks!  1. Yes,  I have set lv.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);  2. I'm not sure if I the adapter has stable IDs, but getCheckItemIds() can return correct value. I hope that I always can get the sum of checked items no matter it  has stable IDs or not. How can I do ? Thanks!